# How do i turn the SharePoint 'Default tick-box pop-up filter' into a 'Dropdown filter'?

Tags: 2013, jquery, dropdown, cascading-dropdown

As above, how do i turn the SharePoint default tick-box pop-up filter into a dropdown filter?

Here's the current filter screens:

The filter on the home page- (Sending values to search in the list)

[image]

The pop-up tick-box filter once you click on the 'filter' button. -

[image]